# How do I change only letters in a string, leaving spaces, hyphens and apostrophes?

Tags: java, regex, string

In my program, a random line (called `ThingToGuess`) is selected from a text file and is changed so that every letter after the third is replaced with an asterisk (this string of asterisks is called `NumberOfBlanks`), and the user has to guess what the original string was using the first three letters.

However, the spaces, apostrophes and hyphens must be left in the new string. For example, the string, `Man in the mirror` would be changed to `Man ** *** ******`

What I have only outputs `Man *************`.

```
String NumberOfBlanks = "";
for(int i=1; i<ThingToGuess.length(); i++){
    NumberOfBlanks = NumberOfBlanks +"*";
}
String OutputCharacters = ThingToGuess.substring(0,3)+ NumberOfBlanks;
OutputCharacters = OutputCharacters.substring(0,secondIndex)+' '+OutputCharacters.substring(secondIndex+1);
System.out.println(OutputCharacters);
```

How do I change `ThingToGuess` to a string wherein only the letters are replaced with asterisks?

Comment: What about `replaceAll` with a regex for any letter?

Comment: @Dodo - On a side note, you should follow [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `NumberOfBlanks` should be `numberOfBlanks`, `ThingToGuess` should be `thingToGuess` and `OutputCharacters` should be `outputCharacters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```java
String input = "Man in the mirror";
String output = input.substring(0,3) + input.substring(3,input.length()).replaceAll("[^ -\']","*");
System.out.println(output); // Prints "Man ** *** ******"
```

We are doing two things, taking first three characters as it is and for remaining characters, we are replacing all characters except SPACE, HYPHEN and APOSTROPHE with ASTERISK

Comment: Thanks Sanjay for adding Apostrophe in list, I missed that in question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when you're iterating and appending to a string, its better to use a StringBuilder. As using the + operator in the loop increases the runtime of the program. More info [here](http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/02/the-optimum-method-to-concatenate.html)

Answering to your question:

```java
String s = "Man in the mirror";
        char[] charArr = s.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<charArr.length;i++)
        {
            if((charArr[i]!=' ' || charArr[i]!='\'' || charArr[i]!='-') && i>2){
                charArr[i]='*';
            }
        }
        s= new String(charArr);
        System.out.println(s);
```

This method tackles the problem directly. It can also be solved by Regex as Hemang illustrated

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use this method to check if a char is a letter or a number and convert the char to "*" only if they are.

```
Character.isDigit(yourchar) || Character.isLetter(yourchar)
```

Comment: Or simply `Character.isLetterOrDigit(char)`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using regex:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String thingToGuess = "Man in the mirror";
        String result = thingToGuess.substring(0, 3) + thingToGuess.substring(3).replaceAll("[^\\s'-]", "*");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Man ** *** ******
```

The `^` inside the `[]` of the regex pattern specifies *None of the characters from this list of characters`.

**Non-regex solution:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String thingToGuess = "Man in the mirror";
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        output.append(thingToGuess.substring(0, 3));
        for (int i = 3; i < thingToGuess.length(); i++) {
            char ch = thingToGuess.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
                output.append('*');
            } else {
                output.append(ch);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or 8+

```
public static String maskLettersAndDigits(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    return IntStream.range(0, chars.length).mapToObj(i -> i > 2 && Character.isLetterOrDigit(chars[i]) ? "*" : String.valueOf(chars[i])).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```